# How to get items in a list before and after a specified index

Tags: python, python-2.7, list-comprehension

Suppose I have the list `f=[1,2,3]` and index `i` -- I want to iterate over `f`, excluding `i`. Is there a way I can use `i` to split the list, something like `f[:i:]`, where I would be given a new list of `[1,3]` when ran with `i=1`?

Code I'm trying to fit this into:

```
# permutations, excluding self addition
# <something here> would be f excluding f[x]
f = [1,2,3]
r = [x + y for x in f for y in <something here>]

# Expected Output (notice absence of any f[i]+f[i])
[3, 4, 3, 5, 4, 5]
```

Comment: Is `f = [10,20,30,40,50,60];
ind = 3;
f_new = f[:ind]+f[ind+1:];
print(f_new);` what you mean by self-addition?

Comment: I've updated my question for clarity

Comment: @MrDuk... so, you're trying to loop through a list and on each iteration create a new list which excludes the current index? It's not very clear from your question what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) in order to have access to index at iteration time.

```
[item for i, item in enumerate(f) if i != 3]
```

In this case you can escape the intended index or if you have a set of indices you can check the membership with `in`:

```
[item for i, item in enumerate(f) if i not in {3, 4, 5}]
```

If you want to remove an item in a certain index you can use `del` statement:

```
>>> l = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
>>> 
>>> del l[3]
>>> l
['a', 'b', 'c', 'e']
>>>
```

If you want to create a new list by removing that item and preserve teh main list you can use a simple slicing:

```
>>> new = l[:3] + l[4:]
>>> new
['a', 'b', 'c', 'e']
```

Comment: Thanks, but the assignment of `i` in the question is just an example -- I want to split a list `f` into a new list, excluding `i`, every iteration

Answer (score 0):

iterate y over the index:

```
f = [10,20,30,40,50,60]
r = [x + f[y] for x in f for y in range(len(f)) if f[y] != x]
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the most elegant solution, but this might work:

```
f = [1,2,3,4,5]

for i, x in enumerate(f):
    if i == 0:
        new_list = f[1:]
    elif i == len(f) -1:
        new_list = f[:-1]
    else:
        new_list = f[:i]+f[i+1:]
    print i, new_list
```

prints:

```
0 [2, 3, 4, 5]
1 [1, 3, 4, 5]
2 [1, 2, 4, 5]
3 [1, 2, 3, 5]
4 [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, it may seem scary but that's a one-liner that does the work:

```
>>> from numpy import array
>>> import itertools
>>> list(itertools.chain(*(i+array(l) for i,l in zip(reversed(f), itertools.combinations(f, len(f)-1)))))
[3, 4, 3, 5, 4, 5]
```

If you look at it slowly, it's not so complicated:

1. The `itertools.combination` give all the possible options to the `len(f)-1` combination:

   ```
   >>> list(itertools.combinations(f, len(f)-1))
   [(1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3)]
   ```
2. You wrap it with `zip` and `reversed(f)` so you can get each combination together with the missing value:

   ```
   >>> [(i,l) for i,l in zip(reversed(f), itertools.combinations(f, len(f)-1))]
   [(3, (1, 2)), (2, (1, 3)), (1, (2, 3))]
   ```
3. Then you convert `l` to a `numpy.array` so you can add the missing value:

   ```
   >>> list((i+array(l) for i,l in zip(reversed(f), itertools.combinations(f, len(f)-1))))
   [array([4, 5]), array([3, 5]), array([3, 4])]
   ```
4. And finaly you use `itertools.chain` to get the desired result.